# How to add custom manifest to Fargate cluster using CDK?

Tags: c#, aws-cdk, amazon-eks

I am able to create an EKS Fargate cluster using CDK (C# library). I am trying to apply a simple K8s manifest to create a namespace in the cluster, but while execution it fails with below error.

> 20/26 | 1:56:15 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-KubernetesResource | eks-ew1-examples-dev/manifest-ns/Resource/Default (eksew1examplesdevmanifestns550D618B) Failed to create resource. Error: b'error: error validating "/tmp/manifest.yaml": error validating data: invalid object to validate; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false\n'

Below is the code snippet to add the manifest.

```
var nsManifest = "{\"apiVersion\": \"v1\", \"kind\": \"Namespace\", \"metadata\": { \"name\": \"examples\"}}";
cluster.AddManifest("ns", nsManifest);
```

My end goal is to create a ServiceAccount in this namespace with necessary permissions to DynamoDb. The ServiceAccount Construct has a namespace property but it expects the namespace to be already present in the cluster to work. Any feedback would be of great help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

As explained [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11483), you are meant to pass objects into .AddManifest(), not the JSON/YAML string.